# Difference between JDK7 or 8?

Tags: java

I am planning on learning Java. Now, the tutorial I want to follow uses Java SE Development Kit 7, but on the site I have noticed Java SE Development Kit 8 is already available. Now i'm not really sure which version to use.

Is there any major difference between the versions? Or will I be fine using Java SE Development Kit 8 while the tutorial uses 7?

Comment: this will get closed soon, I would say latest stable always (`1.8_05` as of now -> go for it)

Comment: In this case, I would grab both.  Default to Java 8, but if you have issues, try it again in Java 7 to make sure if it's subtle change in the versions or something you've done wrong...

Comment: Its worth noting that unlike some other languages (he says looking down his nose) java is 99.9% backwards compatible so anything you learn for java 7 (such as this tutorial) will work in java 8 (there might just be a better way of doing it in java 8)

Comment: I've heard that there are may be some cases where something that compiles on Java 7 doesn't compile on Java 8.  However, the person that told me this never provided an example after I asked.  There may be some cases where changes to the overload resolution rules cause some method calls to be ambiguous that weren't ambiguous before.  Anyway, I wouldn't worry about it.  You probably have to be doing something really weird to run into this.

Comment: How is this even opinion based? Either there is a difference or there is not.. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Java 8 was released only a few months ago, so for the time being there will be more depth and breadth available in terms of learning resources for Java 7.  For the majority of the language features you will use, particularly starting out, these resources will be just fine.

See this documentation regarding the new features introduced with Java 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html#javase8. The most notable is probably lambda expressions, which allow a certain measure of functional programming within Java's mainly object-oriented paradigm.

Comment: @Dieter91 the title probably makes the question look opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. you will be fine.

Everything you can do on 7 you will be able to do on 8.

AFAIK 8 just brings new features and deprecates some stuff but they should still work fine.
If you're beginning java most of the updates won't matter to you.

See [what's new in JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html)

Comment: Thank you. However i just found out that JDK8 does not work on android. Just thought i'd share this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dieter91 Android is a little bit of a special case (oracle got quite upset about it - android programs don't run on other java powered machines and normal java programs don't run on android, breaking a major advantage of java). I think android was until recently java-6 only and even now parts of java 7 don't work with it (for example try-with-resources).